# Automatic selection of file in editing

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to enable the automatic selection in "project explorer" of the current file in editing? 
(In VisualStudio is enabled by menu option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can. Just select autoscroll from source in the settings button that is close to the project infrastructure.

[image: Autoscroll from source]